# Flag parameter doesn't work correctly (SQL)

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have an "AcctMgr_Flag" that designates a person as the account manager. This is on the table Company_Team. If I send parameter @acctmgr as 'true', I want to return only Activities where @member is the account manager. If @acctmgr is not true, I do not care whether AcctMgr_Flag is true or not.

Every Activity in SO_Activity has an "Assigned_To" column which designates a member_recid. Every Member in Company_Team has an AcctMgr_Flag and Company_RecID. Every Member in v_rpt_Member has a member_recid and a Company_recid.

Here is my code

```
SELECT v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, SO_Activity.Subject, SO_Activity.Notes,
       SO_Activity.Date_Closed, SO_Activity.Last_Update, v_rpt_Member.Member_ID,
       v_rpt_ActivityType.SO_Activity_Type_Desc,
       v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_Desc
FROM v_rpt_Company 
LEFT OUTER JOIN SO_Activity 
  ON v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = SO_Activity.Company_RecID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_Member 
  ON SO_Activity.Assign_To = v_rpt_Member.Member_ID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN Company_Team 
  ON v_rpt_Member.Member_RecID = Company_Team.Member_RecID AND 
     v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = Company_Team.Company_RecID 
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_ActivityType 
  ON SO_Activity.SO_Activity_Type_RecID=v_rpt_ActivityType.SO_Activity_Type_RecID
LEFT OUTER JOIN v_rpt_ActivityStatus 
  ON SO_Activity.so_act_status_recid = v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_RecID
WHERE (Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 
       CASE WHEN @acctmgr = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag END) AND 
      (SO_Activity.Assign_To = @member) AND 
      (v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_Desc = 
       CASE WHEN @act_status IS NULL 
            THEN v_rpt_ActivityStatus.so_act_status_desc ELSE @act_status END) AND 
      (v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID = 
       CASE WHEN @company = '' THEN v_rpt_Company.Company_RecID ELSE @company END) AND 
      (SO_Activity.Last_Update >= CONVERT(datetime, @date_start, 101)) AND
      (SO_Activity.Last_Update <= CONVERT(datetime, @date_end, 101))
GROUP BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, SO_Activity.Subject, SO_Activity.Notes,
         SO_Activity.Date_Closed, SO_Activity.Last_Update, v_rpt_Member.Member_ID, 
         v_rpt_ActivityType.SO_Activity_Type_Desc, 
         v_rpt_ActivityStatus.SO_Act_Status_Desc
ORDER BY v_rpt_Company.Company_Name, SO_Activity.Last_Update DESC
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of

```
(Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = CASE WHEN @acctmgr = 'true' THEN 1 ELSE Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag END)
```

Put this

```
(@acctmgr != 'true' or Company_Team.AcctMgr_Flag = 1)
```

Comment: Absolutely Correct. Thank you.